# Unable to login while using salt for password hashing in cakephp3x

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.0, saltedhash

I have 2 fields password and salt in my users table. While saving the data, its working fine & data are being saved into both columns using the following code.

```php
$password = $this->Custom->hashSSHA();
$user->password = $password['encrypted'];
$user->salt = $password['salt'];
```

`$password` is having the following array value.

```php
Array
(
    [salt] => 993ffb0265
    [encrypted] => 8FdzWdZ5jXN3GC+GzkO9p6ee/nk5OTNmZmIwMjY1
)
$password['encrypted'] = 8FdzWdZ5jXN3GC+GzkO9p6ee/nk5OTNmZmIwMjY1993ffb0265.
```

I am attaching my login code below. Here I have manually checked for the password and salt. But its not working.

```php
public function login() {
        $this->viewBuilder()->layout('');
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $data = $this->request->data;            
            $query = $this->Users->find('all')
                    ->select(['Users.id', 'Users.email', 'Users.name', 'Users.password', 'Users.salt', 'Users.is_active'])
                    ->where(['Users.email' => $data['email'], ['Users.is_active' => 1]]);
            $row = $query->first();           
            $number_login = $query->count();

            if ($number_login != 0) {
                $password = $this->Custom->checkhashSSHA($row['salt'], $data['password']);

                if ($password == $row['password']) {
                    $session = $this->request->session();
                    $session->write('User_name', $row['name']);
                    $session->write('User_email', $row['email']);
                    $session->write('User_id', $row['id']);                   
                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);                    
                } else {
                    $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
                }
            } else {

                $this->Flash->error(__('Account not activated yet'));
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description, please be more specific as to what exactly happens, and what should happen instead. Also show your debugging attempts, and add the relevant code, that is, all your custom hashing stuff. On a side note, that's not how you should implement custom auth/hashing mechanisms, you should use CakePHPs authentication layer instead, and use custom authentication and password hasher classes. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html**